# jpaRepository + JPQL + JOIN

Tags: jpql

Eu tenho a `query` abaixo rodando no meu código mas usando os nomes reais da tabela e dos campos, nessa mesma estrutura abaixo funciona, mas como eu faço para fazer o mesmo mas usando a linguagem `JPQL`, estou usando nomes genéricos da tabela e campos só para facilitar o entendimento.

```
@Query(value = "select rc.* from tabela1 i  join tabela2 rc on rc.campoA= i.campoA")                             
public Page<Tabela2> trazerResultado(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendendo que as entidades Tabela1 e Tabela2 não tem um relacionamento entre si, e você quer apenas fazer um `JOIN` entre elas, podemos fazer isto via `WHERE`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT tab2 FROM Tabela1 tab1, Tabela2 tab2 
    WHERE tab1.campoA = tab2.campoA")
```

Nas [versões mais novas](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/) do Hibernate (a partir da 5.1) você pode usar `ON` também, possibilitando fazer consultas entre entidades sem relacionamento:

```
@Query(value = "select rc from Tabela1 tab1 
   JOIN Tabela2 rc ON rc.campoA = tab1.campoA")
```